# How can I edit files in WordPress using my own text editor?

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I want to gain permission to edit my WordPress files with my own text editor, while keeping permissions to create, and delete within my WordPress admin area.

I am using XAMPP to run my localhost server. I am using Ubuntu as my operating system.

If I try to open and edit any file within my WordPress installation using Atom, Brackets, or Sublime Text, I get prompted that I don't have permission to make modifications.

But it allows me to add plugins, download new themes, or edit the files via the WordPress Admin section.

I have tried to do `sudo chown -R me:me /opt/lampp/htdocs` but when I do that I lose the ability to upload, delete, or post anything via the WordPress admin area. But it allows me to make modifications via my own text editor.

When I do `sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /opt/lampp/htdocs` I gain the ability to upload, delete, and post via the WordPress admin area, but I lose the ability to edit anything via my own text editor.

How can I gain permission to edit files via a my own text editor, and still have the ability to upload, delete, or post anything via the WordPress admin area?

Comment: Check out Local By Flywheel instead of using xampp, I think you'll have a better time

Comment: Unfortunately it only supports Windows and Mac. I currently use Linux.

Comment: Oh, if you are using Linux you could just run everything natively

Comment: I am running it natively. I am having issues with the permissions though as I state in my original post.

Comment: I'm sorry the XAMPP part confused me